# How insert value in new column in google sheets using query funtion

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a column shown in the figure I want to add a new column based on the condition morning (6 AM-12 PM), afternoon (12:00:00–18:00:00), evening (18:00:00 24:00:00), and night (24:00:00–06:00:00) so if time is 07:00:00 then the value in my column should be morning. I want to add value to google sheets using the query function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(VLOOKUP(A1:A*1, {
 0, "night"; 
 "6:00:00" *1, "morning"; 
 "12:00:00"*1, "afternoon"; 
 "18:00:00"*1, "evening"}, 2, 1)))
```